# how to batch modify metadata arguments in Field() due to RemovedInMarshmallow4Warning after upgrade marshmallow

Tags: python, backend, marshmallow, coding-efficiency

after upgrade marshmallow, the non-reserved arguments(e.g. `title`, `description`) should passing in by `metadata` argument.

**otherwise, it will pop RemovedInMarshmallow4Warning.**

what if I have a lot of `Field()` call expression, how can I batch modify it quickly?

example code:

```py
# schemas.py
from marshmallow import Schema
from marshmallow import fields


class FooSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(
        required=True,
        title='foo',
        description='foo name')
    relationship = fields.String(
        title='bar', description='foobar')
```

test code(test case):

```py
from schemas import FooSchema


def test_warn():
    INPUT = {
        'name': 'something',
        'relationship': 'others'
    }
    schema = FooSchema()
    data = schema.load(INPUT)
    assert data == INPUT
```

files structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── requirements.txt  # marshmallow==3.3.0
├── schemas.py
└── test_warning.py
```

upgrade marshmallow and duplicate this problem:

```sh
$ pip install -U marshmallow
...
Successfully installed marshmallow-3.14.1

$ pytest test_warning.py
================== test session starts ================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /private/tmp/_
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                     

test_warning.py .                                                                                                                              [100%]

================== warnings summary =================================
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py:218
  /private/tmp/_/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py:218: 
RemovedInMarshmallow4Warning: Passing field metadata as keyword arguments is deprecated. 
Use the explicit `metadata=...` argument instead. 
Additional metadata: {'title': 'foo', 'description': 'foo name'}
    warnings.warn(

.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py:218
  /private/tmp/_/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/marshmallow/fields.py:218: 
RemovedInMarshmallow4Warning: Passing field metadata as keyword arguments is deprecated. 
Use the explicit `metadata=...` argument instead. 
Additional metadata: {'title': 'bar', 'description': 'foobar'}
    warnings.warn(

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
================== 1 passed, 2 warnings in 0.03s ===================
```

the expected code without warning:

```py
...

class FooSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(
        required=True,
        metadata={'title': 'foo', 'description': 'foo name'})
    relationship = fields.String(
        metadata={'title': 'bar', 'description': 'foobar'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question myself, and ended up writing a tool to do the conversion.

https://github.com/LewisHaley/mushmallow

See the 'Installation and running' section of the README.

This may not a lot of use to the original poster any more (15 months too late) but this post still appears on Google when searching for the topic, so may yet be useful to others.